Identify brand of blinds and cord joiner
A cord joiner for one of the shades broke after we moved in. I am having a hard time finding out the brand of the shade and a replacement for the octagon-shaped cord joiner.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Below is what the shade looks like: :
Below is what the cord joiner looks like:


Does it need to be the same exact shape?  A window or 'Blinds and Shades' shop would have better info/choice.

Yes I’d like the replacement to have the same shape because I have 20 other shades that all have the same shape. I am having a lot of trouble finding it online.

Top of the shade have any identifying marks?

Online is good if you know what you want.  Talking to local people is better if looking for a specific object.  There are shops that just deal with blinds/shades, should be a yellow pages section for them.

I'd just pick an attractive knot and tie the ends together...

Given that plastic cord joiners can be had for under a dollar apiece, unless you're married to this particular shape, you could just replace all 20 with new ones for the cost of a yuppie food stamp.
